# "std::vec" vs "alloc::vec"

Tags: vector, rust

Rust contains 2 identical (by API) vec modules:

https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/index.html
https://doc.rust-lang.org/alloc/vec/index.html

What are the differences? Which is preferable to use?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`std::vec` is just `alloc::vec` reexported; it is exactly the same module.

If you want to use `Vec`, you don't even need to import it with `use`, because it's part of the [prelude](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/prelude/). The items defined in the prelude are always imported implicitly. If you need to import other items from that module, write `use std::vec::X;` instead of `use alloc::vec::X;`

---

Why does `alloc` exist? It's made available for those who write Rust applications that don't run on an operating system, or applications that *are* operating systems. `std` provides features that depend on an operating system, but some parts of `std` don't; those were split into smaller crates ([`core`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/core/index.html) and [`alloc`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/alloc/index.html)) that can be reused more easily.

Some library authors have made their dependency on `std` optional through a [feature](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/features.html#feature-unification) defined in the Cargo package. In that case, the library needs to use `core` and `alloc` instead of `std`.

You can tell the compiler that you don't want to use `std` by adding `#![no_std]` to your crate root.